# Error: Error trying to display an error. with PyMNE

Tags: julia

I have a huge problems after updating PyMNE to v0.2.0.
It shows very strange behavior, especially interacting with other packages

It can give this kind of error, or go to eternal installation, or some its functions do not work.

This error happens after:

```
using Makie
using TopoPlots
using PyMNE
```

[image]

I tryed to do it in REPL, but it crashes and error message disappears immediately.
So I even do not understand what is the problem.

Do you have any ideas what to do?